# Transition using radio-buttons

Tags: css, css-transitions

I found [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/06/12/css-only-responsive-layout-with-smooth-transitions/), which introduces a transition that I need for my for my page to slide it down with a single click using radio buttons.

The idea is, that my page's `width` and `height` are `100%` and each click moves the page "off the canvas" using `translateY` (found at `tyyli.css` line 663) just like in the tutorial provided.

After all efforts I can't get it work if I put the first radio button inside `st-scroll` div. I have to put it directly under `site-wrapper` to get it work but now is looks horrible, because it wont move along with the page and just hides under `st-scroll`. Also the dot putted outside `st-scroll` DIV causes the whole page to be 100px lower than it thould be.

This is the top radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-1"/>
<a href="#st-panel-1" class="arrow-down up"></a>
```

Try to move this code from the first `<secton>` to just under `site-wrapper` like this

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" class="button i"></a>
    <a href="http://facebook.com/Kadnnn" target="_blank" class="button f"></a>
    <a href="mailto:mymail@mymail.fi" class="button e"></a>
</div>
/*TRY TO PUT IT JUST BELOW THIS LINE AND SEE THE PROBLEM*/
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-1"/>
<a href="#st-panel-1" class="arrow-down up"></a>
<div class="st-scroll">
```

and you will see the problem. My idea is, that this has something to do with the Z-index, but i might be wrong. I want to place both buttons inside `st-scroll`.

My site is [www.kasperikoski.fi](http://www.kasperikoski.fi)

Comment: We'd need to see the CSS but this feels like an issue with the toggle and targeted element not being siblings any more,

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that the links only work outside the div is because the effect is driven by the CSS: `#st-control-#:checked ~ .st-scroll` which means it looks for a sibling DOM element with .st-scroll class.  You need to either have it on the outside of the scroll element or rely on javascript to trigger the same transforms by adding/removing certain classes.

I could see it being done various ways, although the fastest (me being lazy and all) would be something like:

In html:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-1" value="scroll-1">
```

... further down

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-set" id="st-control-2" value="scroll-2">
```

In a script including jquery to save time...:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var scroll = $('.st-scroll');
       $('input[name="radio-set"]').click(function() {
             var which = $(this).attr('value');
             var prev = scroll.data('current');
             if(prev) scroll.removeClass(prev);
             scroll.addClass(which)
                   .data('current',which);
       });
});
```

And finally the css:

```
.scroll-1 {
   transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.scroll-2 {
   transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly... let's say that i want to use animations on every H1 and <p> like in the example given at the tutorial of my project. How does yous modifications effect that. All radio buttons are now located inside .st-scroll <div>.

Answer (score 1):

You can use labels to control radio buttons, so you can put the labels wherever you want and have more control over styling them, as well as hide the radios. However, the radios must be siblings of the element you want to control or one of its ancestors if you want to use the `~` or `+` combinators.

**DEMO**

```css
.st-scroll {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}

input[name="radio-set"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

input[type="radio"] + label {
  display: inline-block;
}

#st-control-1 ~ .st-scroll {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

#st-control-1:checked ~ .st-scroll {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="st-control-1" name="radio-set" checked="checked" />
<div class="st-scroll">
  <label for="st-control-1">I'm a label in .st-scroll but am linked to #st-control-1 so I can control my parent</label>
<input type="radio" id="st-control-2" name="radio-set" />
<label for="st-control-2">I'm a label linked to the other radio</label>
</div>
```